# Is there a way to make StringIO reading blocking

Tags: python, blocking, stringio

I've searched through the documentation and searched around but there is nothing said about blocking StringIO objects.

I could create my own file-like object that just simply wraps around StringIO but how is the best way to make it blocking? The only way I know is to use a while loop and a time.sleep(0.1) till there is data available.

Comment: What exactly would block it? You're reading from a string.

Comment: StringIO is a file-like object, so it both has a '' EOF and a .close() method that makes all other read()'s raise an exception, I want that EOF to just be blocking instead of.. returning an EOF.

Comment: Perhaps you want a pipe instead then.

Comment: I was going to ask how you expected a `StringIO` object to unblock when strings are immutable, but then I actually looked at the documentation and saw that this limitation applies only to the fast implementation, `cStringIO`, which you can either read from or write to but not both. I presume you have another thread that will do the writing.

Comment: Yes, I have another thread reading from it. It has to be cross-platform else I could've used the 'pipes' module which is unix only. So creating my own file-like object with blocking is the best approach I'm taking then. Is the sleep(0.1) method the best for that?

Comment: There are better ways to share info between threads.  You should check out Queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os

r, w = os.pipe()
r, w = os.fdopen(r, 'rb'), os.fdopen(w, 'wb')
```

Works exactly as I needed, this pipe function is sadly not very obvious in the documentation so I only found it later on.

Answer (score -1):

No, It's pretty obvious looking at the implementation of `read()`

```
def read(self, n = -1):
    """Read at most size bytes from the file
    (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes).

    If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF
    is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty
    string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately.
    """
    _complain_ifclosed(self.closed)
    if self.buflist:
        self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
        self.buflist = []
    if n is None or n < 0:
        newpos = self.len
    else:
        newpos = min(self.pos+n, self.len)
    r = self.buf[self.pos:newpos]
    self.pos = newpos
    return r
```

There is also this note at the top of the file

```
Notes:
- Using a real file is often faster (but less convenient).
```

So you may be better off using a real file anyway