# Write function result to stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I'm trying to write the results of a function to stdin.

This is the code :

```
def testy():
    return 'Testy !'

import sys
sys.stdin.write(testy())
```

And the error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin_test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.stdin.write(testy())
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

I'm not completely sure, is this the right way of doing things ?

Comment: What are those things you're trying to do? `stdin` is for reading input, it's opened read-only.

Comment: Yes I know. What I want to do is simulate keystrokes to the input() method by writing into stdin.

Comment: The traceback is telling you that it's not writable... did you read that?

Comment: @sandeepraju Yes, but it's not very helpful in trying to achieve what I wrote in my comment just above.

Comment: @Awake It would help to have some context:  Why do you want to imitate keystrokes in `input()`?

Comment: Because I have a program that originally was in a shell and now it's using a GUI. What I want to do is convert click events into a string (done) and pipe the result to the previously used input() method.

Comment: Where I previously would ask the user to write 1, 2, or 3 for selecting options I know have three places on the GUI where the user can click on. The event.x and event.y are then converted into a special string and piped to input().

Comment: Maybe you should invoke the old program for the new, separate one, and just pipe input to it.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @PavelAnossov there are too many function calls. drewk : Linux

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could mock `stdin` with a file-like object?

```
import sys
import StringIO

oldstdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO('asdlkj')

print raw_input('.')       #  .asdlkj
```

Comment: I think I'm going to try this solution. Thanks !

Comment: For Python 3: `from io import StringIO` and `sys.stdin = StringIO('asdlkj')`.

Comment: Note that `sys.stdin` does *not* exhibit all the same behavior as `StringIO` and vice versa; for instance `StringIO.readline()` returns an empty string immediately and does not block/wait for input, like `sys.stdin.readline` or `input` does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929689/is-there-a-way-to-make-stringio-reading-blocking for a solution to *that* problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was googling how to do this myself and figured it out.  For my situation I was taking some sample input from hackerrank.com and putting it in a file, then wanted to be able to use said file as my `stdin`, so that I could write a solution that could be easily copy/pasted into their IDE.  I made my 2 python files executable, added the shebang.  The first one reads my file and writes to `stdout`.

```
#!/Users/ryandines/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonPractice-U9gvG0nO/bin/python
# my_input.py
import sys

def read_input():
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/Users/ryandines/Projects/PythonPractice/swfdump')]
    for my_line in lines:
        sys.stdout.write(my_line)
        sys.stdout.write("\n")

read_input()
```

The second file is the code I'm writing to solve a programming challenge.  This was mine:

```
#!/Users/ryandines/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonPractice-U9gvG0nO/bin/python
def zip_stuff():

    n, x = map(int, input().split(' '))
    sheet = []

    for _ in range(x):
        sheet.append( map(float, input().split(' ')) )

    for i in zip(*sheet): 
        print( sum(i)/len(i) )

zip_stuff()
```

Then I use the operating system's pipe command to provide the buffering of STDIN.  Works exactly like hackerrank.com, so I can easily cut/paste the sample input and also my corresponding code without changing anything.  Call it like this: `./my_input.py | ./zip_stuff.py`

Comment: Hey thanks, this is exactly the same use case as I have :)
Works like a charm!

Comment: Hey Ryan, nicely done. Do you know you can directly use a file as input with the command line, so that you don't need to write your first program at all? Or am I missing something?:
`./zip_stuff.py < '/Users/ryandines/Projects/PythonPractice/swfdump'`

Comment: @tharibo yep, you're right, or just cat the file `cat swfdump | ./zip_stuff.py`, although for hackerrank I needed some specific behavior...i dont really remember TBH

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on Linux:

```py
import fcntl, termios
import os
tty_path = '/proc/{}/fd/0'.format(os.getpid())

with open(tty_path, 'w') as tty_fd:
        for b in 'Testy !\n':
            fcntl.ioctl(tty_fd, termios.TIOCSTI,b)
# input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` is an input stream, not an output stream. You can't write to it.

What you might be able to do, possibly, is create a pipe using `os.pipe`, turn the readable end into a file object using `os.fdopen`, and replace stdin with that, and then write to the writeable end.

```
r, w = os.pipe()
new_stdin = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
old_stdin, sys.stdin = sys.stdin, new_stdin
```

I can't see that ending well, though. It will be easier and less error-prone to just rewrite the parts of your application that are using `input`.

Comment: While it does not solve this question, [turns out you can write to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898574/)