# How to output to custom file descriptor?

Tags: python

C code:

```
write(3, "str", sizeof("str") - 1);
```

Usage: ./a.out 3>/dev/stdout

How to achieve the same functionality in Python? From documentation I should call open function and use given file descriptor. But what if I already have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something similar in python. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898984/8243) for a more detailed description.

It'll look something like:

```
yourfd = open(3, "w")
yourfd.write("str")
yourfd.close()
```