# Python zero as file parameter in open function

Tags: python

I'm currently puzzling around this piece of code.

What exactly does

```py
open(0)
```

do?

I already looked up the docs or tried to find something in the internet but no clues.

The codesnippet where this code is used:

```py
map(abs,map(int,open(0).read().split()))
```

Thanks ^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer File Descriptor "0" in open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898231/integer-file-descriptor-0-in-open)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0` is the file descriptor associated with `stdin` (`1` corresponds to `stdout`, `2` to `stderr`). `open` takes `int` file descriptors as an argument, not just paths, so passing `0` is legal. This is just a somewhat obscure way to create a file object bound to `stdin` without needing to `import sys`.

The flaw with it is that, when it is closed, it will close the file descriptor `0` (since `closefd=False` was not passed), so `sys.stdin` will be closed without realizing it (though it'll probably figure it out when if someone tries to use it).

Comment: So it will just read input, right? Nevermind, got it now