# How does stdin work with open(0) in Python?

Tags: python, terminal

I found some code which inputs data like so:

```
n, *b = open(0)
```

The input is a bunch of lines of numbers, so presumably the first line should be saved to n and the rest of the lines saved to b.

How exactly do you input the lines using stdin? For example, I open the conda terminal and type `python test.py` and hit enter. Then I copy the text into the terminal and hit enter but nothing happens. What exactly is the format required if you have a text file with lines of numbers, to input these lines and save them into the n and b variables using open(0)?

Comment: `python test.py < textFileWithLinesOfNumbers.txt` perhaps.  If you pasted the text into the running Python program, you'd have to explicitly indicate an End-Of-File (Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z) to terminate the input.

Comment: My guess is they have defined their own `open` function that hides the Python builtin.  I don't know of any conditions under which `open` returns multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answer, the code in question works. I tested it.

`open(0)` [creates a file object that represents the standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898231/integer-file-descriptor-0-in-open) (unless you have remapped the file descriptors first). A file is iterable; iterating over it gives the lines of the file. Writing something like `n, *b =` unpacks the right-hand side; this entails iterating over it.

To provide the input by typing it in at the terminal, therefore: each value should be on a separate line; and the end of file needs to be indicated [by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux/Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197025/).

Seeing it in action:

```
$ echo 'n, *b = open(0); print(n, b)' > bizarre.py
$ python bizarre.py 
1
2
3
1
 ['2\n', '3\n']
```

The `1`, `2` and `3` are input by me; then I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to indicate the end of input. That stops the iteration so that the unpacking can complete and the rest of the program can proceed; the `1` and the list are output from the program. (There is a space before the list because that is the default `sep` for `print`; the values are on separate lines because `n` is actually equal to the string `'1\n'`.)

Alternately, you can redirect data from a file:

```
$ cat > data.txt
1
2
3
$ python bizarre.py < data.txt 
1
 ['2\n', '3\n']
```

Here I simply used `cat` to create the text file for a self-contained example; but you can produce it by any method. We use the terminal to redirect the file to Python's standard input. Since it's now reading from a file, there is already an end-of-file and we don't need any more babysitting.

Comment: open(0) tricks are very useful in code golf